# Flatten a Nested JSON Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to flatten a nested JSON Array in PHP, the list I have is:

```
["Paris", "Barcelona", ["Glasgow", ["Sydney"]]]],"Budapest"]
```

So far I have this code:

```
<?php
$array = [
'city' => [
    'Paris',
    'Berlin',
    'London',
],
];

$flattened = iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)
), false);

print_r($flattened);
```

I needs to use this

```
print_r((new Flattener($jsonArray))→flatten());
```

This command should return a single-dimensional PHP array.

Any ideas of what I am missing?

Comment: So, what does it return instead?

Comment: Or are you asking how to create a Flattener object from the code you currently have?

Comment: currently it returns the array : `Array ( [0] => Paris [1] => Berlin [2] => London )`

Comment: But that is a single-dimensional array.

Comment: okay so is it correct then? how would I use the `print_r((new Flattener($jsonArray))→flatten());` in what I have?

Comment: You'd have to create a Flattener class that takes an array in its constructor and put the code you currently have into its flatten method.

Comment: Just to be clear, you already have code that flattens a multidimensional array, so this question really is more about creating a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

1. create a class with a constructor (**__construct**) that takes the array and
2. create a flatten method which takes the array and flattens it.

An example you could use:

```
class Flattener {

  private $array;

  public function __construct($array) {
    $this->array = $array;
  }

  public function flatten() {
    return iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
      new RecursiveArrayIterator($this->array)), false);
  }

}

print_r((new Flattener($array))->flatten());
```